# Will old posts be reposted?

Tags: discussion, questions

If there are old posts, or posts that have been unanswered for a certain amount of time, will they be resubmitted automatically after a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the community user will bump older questions about every hour. Though ideally the best way to bump your question is to add more information to it, share your research, and so on.